# Uploading a file to Amazon S3, update a database and return a response

Tags: node.js, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I see how to upload to Amazon S3 (from the client) and I see how to make requests to update a dynamoDB (from the client) but how do I upload a file to S3 such that I get a response back with "business logic" information?

For instance, I want to upload a photo to a `uploadPhoto` endpoint that will return to me the `photoID` of the photo in my dynamoDB model.

Yes I can upload a file to S3 and have it 'notify' Lambda but then its too late, S3 has already returned a response, Lambda can't *send another response* back to the client.

Its clear I shouldn't upload a file *to* Lambda.

So there is the API Gateway, its not clear that its a 'good idea' to upload files to API Gateway...

Comment: You will have to create the service that exists at the uploadPhoto endpoint yourself.

Comment: Agreed, but what AWS 'service' do I use to make _my_ service?

Comment: EC2, Lambda, Elastic Beanstalk, API Gateway... There are many possible answers to your question. I would look into Lambda. I would recommend reading the descriptions of each service on AWS instead of relying on strangers to tell you what you should use.

Comment: Lets assume I've spent a lot of time reading doco and prototyping before I posted here.  The problem is its clear that you can upload files to S3 and its clear you can make HTTP requests and get responses from Lambda, API Gateway etc, what isn't clear (anywhere, seriously google it) is how you would upload a file > perform business logic > return a response given that business logic.

Comment: That's because you are searching for a very specific service that doesn't exist out of the box. Something that takes a request, performs business logic, and returns a response is a service. You need to research how to build and deploy services on AWS, and how to get your service to accept file uploads.

Answer (score 2):

We just went through a similar scenario and unfortunately I think it comes down to 2 choices:

1. Use multiple requests - Client calls lambda to get presigned url, client uploads file directly to s3, then client calls back to lambda, lets it know the file has been uploaded and gets a response with all the business logic
2. One request - Create a service(likely on ec2) that sits in front of s3, so your client uploads directly to your service, your service then uploads to s3, does the business logic, and then sends the response back to the client. Definitely less work on the client but you get charged for twice as much bandwidth because you are uploading it twice.

We implemented #1 and it wasn't too hard. In our case the client is an Angular app so to the user it looks like one request but behind the scenes the app is making several calls.

Comment: Very helpful suggestions, I agree that #1 seems like the easiest to implement but #2 seems more 'robust', especially if I can use the new API Gateway instead of EC2 but there aren't many examples of S3 + API Gateway.  Thanks for pointing out that #2 would involve uploading twice

Comment: I wasn't able to find a way to upload through API Gateway, it may be possible - but I sure couldn't find anything on it. It was a chore just to get it to accept application/x-www-form-urlencoded POSTs. See this mapping template https://gist.github.com/ryanray/668022ad2432e38493df